# Textual representation of geometrical shapes

Tags: geometry, shapes, properties-file

In my application I want to store *shapes* in a property file. Currently points and rectangles, but perhaps will be enhanced to other shapes like circles, etc. in the future.

It's clear to me that I can store them just as tuple of values, e.g. for a rectangle `5,7,80,60`, or as list of named attributes, e.g. `x=5,y=7,width=80,height=60`. But I would like to have something less technical and more conventional when opening the file with a text editor.

So, for points there is a common (mathematical) notation `(x|y)` (sometimes `(x,y)`) which leads to my question:

**Is there any standardized or common textual notation for geometrical shapes?**

I'm aware of [Well-known text (WKT)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-known_text) but it's using the tuple approach which I don't find very readable.

Some side-notes:

- At least the most common shapes like squares/rectangles, circles/ellipses, triangle would be great.
- I don't put any constraints on easy parsing.
- Mathematical representations that can be transformed to a simple text representation would be acceptable, too.
- I also accept "No." as an answer.

Comment: There is e.g. svg and html canvas.  Maybe you can use a standard that allows comments, like `circle 15, 3, 6 #center x, center y, radius`?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I'm looking for a representation and not a technique how to put it into a file. Also using XML like in SVG is a bit "too heavy-weight" for my use-case and would come up similar to the "named attributes" example given.

Comment: I think you will have more luck on some math site as you are basically asking for math notation ... Also look at some CAD/CAM CGS tools. They usually have tree views of the geometry properties may be you will like it

Comment: I'll take this into account. Thanks.